# JAXB: xjc and fixed values for attributes of derived types

Tags: xsd, jaxb, xjc

I'm trying to create an xsd with a type hierarchy.
What I'm hoping to archieve is that the subtypes fill the base type's attributes with a certain value.
This is my best result:

```
<xs:complexType name="base_type">
    <xs:attribute name="att" use="required" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="type1_t">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="base_type">
            <xs:attribute name="att" fixed="value1" use="required" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="type2_t">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="base_type">
            <xs:attribute name="att" fixed="value2" use="required" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

The "att" attribute is made available by base_type, and in elements of type1_t and type2_t, I'd like them set to "value1" and "value2", respectively.

The container element looks like this:

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="type1" type="type1_t" />
            <xs:element name="type2" type="type2_t" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Now I'm running xjc to generate Java classes for this code, but the "fixed" attribute is not represented in what I get in the Type1T.java, which consists only of

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "type1_t")
public class Type1T extends BaseType { }
```

I would have expected

```
{
  @Override public String getAtt() { return "value1"; }
}
```

?
That is (almost) what gets generated when the type is generated by itself (ie not as an extension of a base type).

I'm I doing something wrong? Is what I'm trying to do just not possible?

My goal is to automatically generate all java code from xsd; otherwise I suppose a way to implement this would be to code the fixed values in the created ObjectFactory methods for each class manually. However, then I would need to prevent ObjectFactory from getting generated every time...

Any hints? Tips? Thoughts?